# Sinatra hangs seemingly without a reason

Tags: ruby, ajax, sinatra

I have a strange problem with sinatra...

In my app the login form is checking with AJAX live whether a nickname is already taken or free... This works fine 90% of the time... But sometimes, randomly, I get no response from the given route anymore... in the console log all new requests to this route are missing as if I haven't sent anything... but other routes seem to be fine...

And when that occurs, if I shutdown sinatra, it begins to obviously hang. it says:

```
[2010-08-29 22:41:12] INFO  going to shutdown ...
```

but the process does not terminate anymore until I close the console window.

I checked my client side code - it works fine... I also checked the code in the route itself... (only about 7 lines) - its fine too (the only method, the one which accesses the database, works flawlessly in all other circumstances)

So the only explaination I came up with that it must be a Sinatra bug...

Has someone experienced something similar? If not... do you agree? Should I file a bug report? And what shall I write into that report? The bug is much too... random...

```
UPDATE:
    enable :lock unfortunately doesn'nt help...
    I tried to use hijack... it doesn't seem to work on the process
    (I used the pid given by WEBrick)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that causes this? It could be that you have a race condition that's causing some sort of lockup. Try `enable :lock` in your sinatra config.

Comment: I don't know what exactly causes this... you can see everything here:
http://github.com/apirogov/Aphorism

see "check_nickname" in ajax_funcs.rb and its counterpart in login.js...

Comment: Just to verify... you can see the request being made in your browser, but you don't get the log message on your sinatra app?  Or you see the request coming in on the server side, but it never responds to the client?

Comment: the first thing - I see the post being sent (in Firebug)... the post is completely fine - just waiting for response...

Comment: is it the same on jruby?

Comment: I didn't try to run it on jruby (I don't even have a jruby enviroment set up for running it (a lot of gems))... Do you have reasons to assume it is the fault of the interpreter? oO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, must have been activerecords fault, after all...

I switched to DataMapper and the bug was gone..